# load json data to javascript global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var locations = [];
$.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {
  console.log(json);
  json.forEach(function(locItem){
    locations.push(locItem);
  });
});

console.log(locations);
```

The line 3 log did print my json list but the line 9 log only gives []. I tried using window.locations, global.locations or define something like

```
var self = this;
```

in global scope and then use self.locations inside the funciont. None of them works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the order of execution is as follows:

```
// create empty array
var locations = [];

// attempt to get json file (locations is unchanged)
$.getJSON("locations.json", callback); 

// print out empty locations variable
console.log(locations);

// json is finally retrieved, and the callback function is processed
function callback(json) {
    console.log(json);
    json.forEach(function(locItem){
        locations.push(locItem);
    });
});
```

The callback function is not called until the json has been retrieved. It does not *wait* for that to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
   var locations = [];
    $.getJSON("locations.json", function(json) {
      console.log(json);
      json.forEach(function(locItem){
        locations.push(locItem);
      });
    }).then(function() {
          console.log(locations);
   });
```